# Consequences of definite versus semi-definite matrix on ellipsoid defined by these matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

In literature, I often see a particular 2nd-rank material tensor $k_{ij}$ claimed as being positive definite.  I've also have seen it claimed as being positive semi-definite.  The former saying that $k=k_{ij}l_il_j>0$, the latter saying $k=k_{ij}l_il_j\geq 0$.

This $k_{ij}$ is often also represented geometrically with the ellipsoid defined as $k_{ij}x_ix_j=+1$, with semiaxes $k_i^{-1/2}$.

Any thoughts you can give that can help me understand (“see”) what implications, if any, there would be for the representation ellipsoid if $k_{ij}$ is positive semi-definite?

What I am currently thinking is that if we let a radius vector $r_i$ from the origin out to the representation ellipsoid's surface at a point $x_i$; then the magnitude of the radius vector is $|r_i|=1/\sqrt k$.  If the tensor $k_{ij}$ is allowed to be semi-definite, then at orientations where $k=k_{ij}l_il_j = 0$ the value of $|r_i|$ will be undefined, and thus a "hole" in the ellipsoid surface. Thoughts?

Comment: In 3D, with one zero eigenvalue, you would have an elliptical cylinder

Comment: In the case of a semi-definite matrix, I think the elipsoid will be non-compact and, depending on the case it might be composed of multiple connected componnents. That is because in the direction where $k_{ij}x_ix_j=0$ the elipsoid blows to infinity

Comment: @mikado is "elliptical cylinder" the 3D terminology for the 2D ellipse? With an eigenvalue of zero, the height (length) of the elliptical cylinder would be zero, no?

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulios I did not see your comment until after I edited my post. Is what you are saying 'in line' with the thought I gave at the end of my edited post?

Comment: No, the “height” wouldn’t be zero. The eigenvalues are the reciprocal squares of the semiaxis lengths.

Comment: @amd ah!, great clarification.

Comment: @Armadillo yes, I think so. Personally I think of the matrix as the components of a semi-defite inner product $<, >$, then the ellipsoid is the unit ball of the inner product. Take $S$ to be the natural unit sphere, then the ellipsoid consists of the points $\frac{x} {\sqrt{<x, x>}} $ for $x\in S$. Therefore as $<x, x>\rightarrow 0$, the point of the ellipsoid in that direction tends to infinity